# Umbraco and Visual Studio 2013 is out of sync

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2013, umbraco, umbraco7

I just got my VS 2013 to run together with Umbraco 7, but i just ran into a poroblem. When i for example create a template inside Umbraco i cant see this newly created template inside of visual studio, but i can see that it exsists in the folder together with all the other templates. And ther eare the same problem countervise when i careate a usercontrol in VS i cant see it inside umbraco, are there any way to make them work in sync?

Or maybe there are some other ways to get intellisence help for umbraco instead of VS IDE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to click on "show all files" and then you'll be able to see it and include in in your project.

[image]